# Duvida básica em LinkedList - Java

Tags: java, lista

Se tenho uma LinkedList chamada Lista que tem size igual a 0, eu posso adicionar um elemento na posição 4 dela, por exemplo?

Answer (score 5):

Não.

O método [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,%20E)) possui a assinatura

```java
public void add(int index, E element)
```

onde `index` é o índice aonde o elemento será inserido e `element` é o elemento a ser inserido.

Tal método lança a exceção [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) se o índice estiver fora do intervalo `(index < 0 || index > size())`.

No seu caso, `4 > 0`, resultando em exceção.